# Does it matter what I eat at the Battle Buffet?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

At the Battle Buffet, there are a number of different dishes you can get. Some of them have bronze covers, some have silver, and some have gold, with the food under each color described in progressively more desirable terms. Sometimes there's up to 5 whatever-units of food left, and sometimes there's as low as 1.

Does any of that actually matter? The in-game explanation doesn't mention any consequences for getting good food or getting lots of food. My best guess is that it affects the item(s?) you get at the end, but that's been a Max Revive every time I've gone.

Answer (score 2):

I have the official Pokémon Sun and Moon guide. It states:

> After you've finished your meal, the hostess will have a look at you to see how satisfied you are. Depending on how full you look, she'll give you one of four rewards: a Honey, a Big Mushroom, an HP Up, or a Max Revive. Keep in mind that it's not just how much you eat, but how delicious the dishes were.

So presumably? The guide only says to see what food goes quickly and what the chefs say to determine their quality.

Answer (score 0):

The colour of the plate determines the level of satisfaction the player gets from eating it. Bronze is a x1 multiplier, while silver is x2, and gold x3.

Bronze and silver minus the player's meal count by 1, whereas gold minuses by 2. In the end, your satisfaction level is what determines your prize.

Lowest satisfaction achieves Honey, low satisfaction achieves a big mushroom, next a HP UP, and then highest satisfaction gets you a max revive.

This all has no effect on how much EXP you gain, though I would suppose if you wanted more you shouldn't battle the golden plate people. Silver plate would be the best for leveling I would suppose.

Comment: Do you have a source for any of this? Does it matter how many whatever-units of food are on a plate?

Comment: As usual [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Buffet) comes in help.

Comment: While Bulbapedia goes into more detail, it has no source for its claims either. Where is any of this coming from?